# How to get underlying data in DataSourceProvider - C#

Tags: c#, wpf

My WPF app is loading the localization strings from Resources.resx file into DataObjectProvider. When I debug in VS I can see the strings' keys and values as static members under "Data", and I can load them in xaml.
However, I need to access these resources in code behind too. DataObjectProvider.Data is of kind DataSourceProvider. How can we get read/access the underlying data by c#?

Comment: you can directly use them in code.
<namespace of resource>.Resources.<key>.
example => Application.Properties.Resources.Resource_Key

Comment: unfortunately this does not work as the application resources is loaded with several merged dictionaries. I can access the dictionary and DataObjectProvider but can't read the static members (resource keys and values).

Answer (score 0):

If you have in xaml ObjectDataProvider in Resource section with some key

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="objectDataProvider" ... />
</Window.Resources>
```

in Window.cs you can get this resource

```
var provider =  FindResource("objectDataProvider) as ObjectDataProvider;
var data  = provider.Data;
```

Comment: Thanks but the question is how do we read the data in provider.Data by C#? in your example, for example data.resourceKey_1. How do we get the value assigned to resourceKey_1?